# Can I force an html element to render a certain media size?

Tags: html, css, meteor

I have an html template (MeteorJS template) that I use on a page of my site.  I'm wanting to reuse that template on another page but I want to render the mobile version of the template because it will act as a widget and not the full template (which is why I want the mobile version).

I'd like to do this without having to override all of the media queries.

Is there a way to tell an element to render all of its children like it is a certain media size?

Comment: That'd be cool if that option existed. Right now there are no selector based media queries. What people do to render at a given size is stick an iframe of that size inside the page. That may not work for your needs. If the CSS of the template is mobile first, you may just need to only copy the css before the min-widths.

Comment: You just copy the code you need into a separate stylesheet. Telling the body to use a certain media query would defeat the purpose of media queries - it wouldn't query anything.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is add a new className to the version of the template that you DO want to obey the media queries.  Then change your media query CSS to only target elements with that new className.

Let's say your base CSS (for mobile and widget) is:

```
.module-a {
    ...
}
.module-a-heading {
    ...
}
```

Then add a new className, let's say `.module-a-fluid` to the instances of `.module-a` that you want to follow your media queries.

```
<div class="module-a module-a-fluid">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Then change your media queries to only target `.module-a`s that also have `.module-a-fluid`.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .module-a.module-a-fluid {
        ...
    }
    .module-a-fluid .module-a-heading {
        ...
    }
}
```